# What is the correct name for this kind of growth expression, is it quadratic growth?! (it's not linear or exponential)?

Tags: exponential-function, nonlinear-dynamics

I've constructed a growth scenario for an energy model and rather than use linear or exponential growth, I'm applying a linear increase rate to the increment amount, not to the base amount.

It's a best fit approach to what I'm looking to achieve with the model, hitting a target capacity in 2030 but starting out with a similar install rate as exists at present.

It's certainly non-linear growth, but it's not strictly exponential growth either (since it's not of the $\boldsymbol{x^n}$ type of geometric equation). Arithmetic growth seems to be defined as linear growth, so that's not arithmetic or geometric I figure.

It's a bit hard to talk about not knowing the correct maths expressions to use so I want to define terms using an example.

I'm asserting that installed Rooftop PV in my state will increases at the rate defined as capacity added in year Y as:

$$Y_n = 257 + 12\times \boldsymbol{n}, \;$$
$\qquad$where $\boldsymbol{n}$ is the  number of years after 2019.

if $C_\boldsymbol{n}$ is the cumulative total at year $\boldsymbol{n}$,

$$ C_\boldsymbol{n} = 1387 + \boldsymbol{n}(257 + 12\times \boldsymbol{n})$$
$$\Leftrightarrow C_\boldsymbol{n}=12 \boldsymbol{n^²} + 257\boldsymbol{n} +1387$$

$$\Rightarrow C_\boldsymbol{n} \approx \frac{\boldsymbol{n}^2 + 21\boldsymbol{n} +116}{12}$$

So can I call it quadratic growth? Does that have common usage enough to be understood in scientific literature around renewable energy?

Here's what it looks like in a table applied year on year for a decade:

[image]

Looking at the last 5 years there's an average *(exponential)* growth rate of 24.5%. I've plotted both the annual additional installs and the annual cumulative installed capacity and the 24.5% fits reasonably for both of them the the historical numbers for 2015-19.

If I project that out as exponential growth it quickly gets to improbably (impossible) amounts in a decade, so exponential growth is not a growth construct I want to use, even using a low rate because the curve is problematic from several practical perspectives.

The graph below plots various rates of change for the additional capacity p.a.
[image]

The graph below plots those same rates of change but showing the cumulative installed capacity.
[image]

Comment: One might think of "parabolic". But no, "quadratic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already shown that the quantity can be described by a quadratic equation, yes, it is quadratic growth.

Comment: Thanks, is that term in common enough usage in scientific papers to be useful?

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil Yes.

Comment: ok thank you...